# Auto align tables in HTML to fill the rows

Tags: javascript, css, html, html-table

I am working on showing members of a group in a single page. The page will be always showed in a kiosk (1920x1080) and I already have a nice dark background.

To represent each member, I want to create a table or div box for lets say 300x150px. Total number of members is not more than 25 at any case (maybe less). So I now want to somehow present these boxes on screen so they look like something like this (well this is only an example, in real case I think each row can have 6 boxes):

[image]

I am scraching my head to figure out how to auto layout these boxes, and so far no success. Here is my CSS and HTML code (never mind the smarty part). Would be nice if you can help me achieve this!)

```
<style type="text/css">
    body{
    background-color: black;
    background-image:url('{$smarty.const.SITE_URL}/core/templates/default/public/bg/{$bgNumber}.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;         
    }   

    .public_h3{
        color: white;
        font-weight: 800;
    }         

    .MAIN_TABLE{
    width: 1800px;
    height: auto;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-color:white;
    }

</style>

<body>
    <center>
        <h3 class="public_h3">My Members</h3>
        <table class="MAIN_TABLE">
            <tr>
                <td> 
                    {foreach name='members' from=$members item=m}
                    <div style="float: left; width:300px; text-align: top;">
                        <table width="100%"  style="padding: 0px">
                            <tr>
                                <td width="100px" >
                                    <img src="{$smarty.const.MEMBERS_IMAGE_URL}/{$m.photo}" width="100" height="100" />
                                </td>
                                <td width="200px" valign="top">
                                    <center><span style="margin: 0; padding: 0" class="member_name">{$m.name}</span></center>
                                    Room: {$m.room}
                                    {$m.rollcall}
                                </td>                             
                            </tr>
                        </table>   
                    </div>
                    {/foreach} 
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </center>    
</body>
```

Comment: A) Don't use the `<center>` tag and 2) post the rendered HTML, not whatever language or template that is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dont use tables for this (please!). Just float some `div`'s and they will auto-flow on to the next row

```
div {
    width: 300px;
    height: 150px;
    border: 10px solid #FFF;
    margin: 10px;
    float: left;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9ZuXa/3/)